# Redirect url with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

I m sure that many people will say that this is duplicated but I try everything from other "Question"`s and nothings work for me.

The problem is that I move my project to the web server.
In this server I have folder "public_html" where I but my project Symfony.
Now to enter on my project I must write the following url: www.mydomain.com/Symfony/web/*
But I want to write a Rewrite Rule which will redirect from www.mydomain.com/Symfony/web/* to
www.mydomain.com/home/*.

To do this I try on 2 different ways with many combination of ReWrite rule.

1. In my public_html I create a .htaccess folder
2. I edit the .htaccess in Symfony/web folder

I add the following rule in both file but without success

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^Symfony/web/(.*)$ www.mydomain.com/home/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Unfortunately without success. What I`m doing wrong?

---

My htaccess file look like

And all the time Error 404 Object not found

Symfony/web/.htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Symfony/web/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+Symfony/web/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^home/(.*)$ $1 [L,NC]

</IfModule>
```

It`s redirecting me but I receive again Object not found :(
I delete the .htaccess in public_html folder which is the root one for my server

public_html\.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^home/(.*)$ /Symfony/web/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: Yes I have it enabled

Answer (score 2):

**1:** Place this code in `/Symfony/web/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Symfony/web/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+Symfony/web/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [L]
```

**2:** Place this code in `/public_html/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^home/(.*)$ /Symfony/web/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: It doesn`t work :( Unfortunately when I remove everything from /Symfony/web/.htaccess and delete also the .htaccess from public_html. It`s redirecting me from www.mydomain.com/Symfony/web/* to www.mydomain.com/home/* but I receive the error 404 "Object not found!"

Comment: See further updates. 2nd rule will be in `/public_html/.htaccess` and make sure to keep only 301 rule in `/Symfony/web/.htaccess`

Comment: I add 2nd rule and left only first in Symfony/web.
It`s redirecting me but Object not found :(

Comment: Ok forget `/Symfony/web/` what happens when you open `www.mydomain.com/home/something`?

Comment: Object not found! Error 404

Comment: Where is `app.php` located for symphony?

Comment: In public_html/Symfony/web

Comment: Almost work. I receive a Symfony error : No route found for "GET /home/something

Comment: Ok I don't know much about symphony. Is there some place where you set `base_url`?

Comment: The problem now is that he is catching www.mydomain.com like a start page. He don`t see /home

Comment: start page is `domain.com/home/` but internals of symfony I don't know.

Comment: This seems to be the problem: http://richardmiller.co.uk/2011/04/08/symfony2-routing-and-mod_rewrite/

Comment: I`m not cathing it :( I`m a little bit confuse why this is not working

Comment: From mod_rewrite we have done everything but looks like Symfony can work with original URL only.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn`t work properly :( I change even my Project url to /home/*  . Home page is showing well but every other url is removing /home/ from url and I`mm receiving 404

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say that your rule is backwards. I think you want your URL to be www.mydomain.com/home/* in the browser... In which case the rule would be reversed. Also, your .htaccess should be in the root and you don't need to include the domain in the rewrite rule because you set a rewrite base.

```
RewriteRule ^home/(.*)$ Symfony/web/$1 [L,R=301]
```